# Rolling out of new AWS services and features

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

Quite often when new AWS services and features are released only in some of the regions and not globally. Is there any reason for it? If it's a new EC2 instance type requiring a new hardware then I can understand rolling in a few regions, but even the small software related features are rolled out incrementally.

For ex., the recent announcement of the [CloudFormation Stack Termination Protection](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/aws-cloudformation-provides-stack-termination-protection/) has been rolled out in 14 regions out of the [total 16 regions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/). It makes it quite difficult with so many services to follow where a particular service and feature is rolled out and not.

Answer (score 1):

14 of 16 is effectively everywhere -- the China and GovCloud regions are not accessible from normal AWS accounts. So, that is a worldwide roll-out.

However, you are correct -- often new services are released in only a few regions (typically N.Virginia and Ireland) with global expansion later.

Answer (score 0):

AWS will release most of it's new features in N.Virginia(us-east-1). After the maturity and success the feature will be implemented in other regions. Why N.Virginia(us-east-1)? For AWS this is the first-most region almost all services are available and having 5 Availability Zones.

For more [See Here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/)